# Getting information from a Raphael object

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm using the raphael javascript svg rendering engine.  If I use the following code

> var canvas = Raphael("canvas",700,500);
> var circ = canvas.circle(30,20,10);
>
> some_function(circ);

is there any way for `some_function` to extract the 30, 20 or 10 from the circle object that has been created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution that might work is using the attr method

```
function some_function(circle){
   return [circle.attr('cx'), circle.attr('cy'), circle.attr('r')]
}
```

which will return array of values

or

```
function some_function(circle){
   return circle.attr(['cx','cy','r']);
}
```

which will return object literal containing all attributes as keys.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!  I knew you could set the attributes with the attr method; I missed the part of the documentation that let you get it too.